# Desktop Shortcut to network drive using group policy

Tags: group-policy, network-share, shortcut

I am looking to create a desktop shortcut to a network drive. We are on a domain, so I am looking to do this via group policy. I would like the shortcut to be placed on the users desktop and be to the network drive of `\\server`. I am having a hard time getting this to work. Most of the forums I have read through only show how to do `\\server\othershare` and not just plain `\\server`. It could be through a script as well, just as long as I can get this to work.

Comment: what is your domain running under? are the DC's 2008? as this can be easily done using group policy preferences

Comment: Yes, we have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Domain controller. I see the shortcut option in Computer configuration-->Preferences-->Windows Settings-->Shortcuts and then new shortcut, how would I go about the settings under new shortcut properties.  In my previous post I do mean double slashes in front of server not just one. Serverfault changed it to one

Answer (score 4):

Tested and work this way. on server 2k8 and windows 7 client:

```
User Configuration->Preferences->Windows Settings->Shortcuts->New
```

and than the details on photo

[image: Instructions]

---

for easy finding you can specify a icon for this shortcut, use .ico file

Comment: It might be helpful if you mention where you found this dialogue box you've provided a screenshot of.  Also, I inlined your image to be helpful.

Comment: done, anyway where a pictured version of the explanation below

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the Shortcut as a Shell Object that points to \\server.  Change the Target Type to Shell Object, then go down to Target Object and select Network -> Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

Group Policy will not create a File System Object direct to a UNC share. So here's what I did:

```
Create or Update Action
Target Type: File System Object
Target Path: C:\windows\explorer.exe
Argument: \\UNCshareofChoice
```

Hope this helps.